# Vue2 - How to add my own properties to the component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am totally new in JS and VueJS and I am giving my first steps with vue.

I want to add in each view an specific property called breadcrumbs:

```
export default {
  name: 'ordersList',
  breadcrumbs: [],
.....
```

I want to get that array later from a my main component (the entry component of the whole app) to create the breadcrumbs of that view.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to pass it to the component from parent component or do you want to use like in component variable? Which version do you use? If it is Vue 3 which API do you use?

Comment: I use vue 2... and I want it to be available in the main component... I call it App.vue and is my entry point for the whole application!

Comment: I will suggest you to pass breadcrumb string `view 1` / `view 2` from router itself so that it will render based on the route dynamically.

Answer (score -3):

If you're using Vue 2 you can add that in like

```js
export default {
  name: 'ordersList',
  data () {
   return {
     breadcrumbs: [],
   }
  }
.....
```

Please have a look at the docs [here](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)